# rewrite word in URL - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting, themes

i am working with wordpress and purchased theme.
Theme generate url http://martin.heskovci.sk/avalon_td_gallery/zvierata/ and i want change it to http://martin.heskovci.sk/portfolio/zvierata/

i tried something in .htacces and functions.php but with no result. I found something in code

```
<a href="'.$avalon_td_post_permalink.'" class="avalon_td_btn"><span>'.esc_html__('View Full Gallery', 'avalon').'</span> <i class="xcon-right-open-big"></i></a>
```

I think that i have to rewrite ".$avalon_td_post_permalink." but i do not know how. Someone help me please?

**UPDATE 1**

I found this one. Where I have to rewrite "avalon_td_gallery"? I tried change rewrite row and last row, but after create a new gallery I get still 404.

```
// Arguments for gallery projects
            $args = array(
                'labels'                => $labels,
                'public'                => true,
                'publicly_queryable'    => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
                'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
                'exclude_from_search'   => false,
                'show_ui'               => true,
                'show_in_menu'          => true,
                'menu_position'         => 4,
                'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-format-gallery', //XXS_PLUGIN_URI . 'assets/img/portfolio-icon.png',
                'can_export'            => true,
                'delete_with_user'      => false,
                'hierarchical'          => false,
                'has_archive'           => true,
                'capability_type'       => 'post',
                'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'avalon_td_gallery', 'with_front' => false ),
                'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' )
            );

            // Register our gallery post type
            register_post_type( 'avalon_td_gallery', $args );
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'avalon_td_gallery', 'with_front' => false ),
```

to this

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false ),
```

and important thing,  Settings -> Permalinks page and hit save. This will flush the rewrite rules and now its working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't make a comment - so I will respond here.

I would first search the project folder for files that contain **avalon_td_gallery**.

Depending on how the theme generates the url - this will decide how you will change the url. If it's made with a Custom Post Type, then you simply change the rewrite rules. The **avalon_td_gallery** would be inside a register_post_type function. And either you change the value, or add a rewrite rule to this function:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),
```

Obviously, you should make sure there are no conflicts using this rewrite rule.

The other way to create custom rewrite rules the 'wordpress way' is add_rewrite_rule function. If you find **avalon_td_gallery** within this, simply change first parameter of the rewrite rule, then update your permalinks in the Wordress. For example:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'avalon_td_gallery/([^/]+)', 'index.php?gallery_item=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE**

So you shouldn't change all instances of avalon_td_gallery in all files. You still want the handler or the query variable to be remain as avalon_td_gallery, you just want the url to change. Here's a very simple exampe of the register_post_type function.

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'label'  => 'Gallery',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'avalon_td_gallery', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

Therefore, only the slug would change. If you changed the register_post_type handler to something else, it will consider it a new post type. So **don't do this**:

```
register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args ); // -< THIS IS WRONG
```

If you can revert the registration of your post type, back to **avalon_td_gallery** gallery, this will keep your data under that namespace, but only change the url.

Comment: Thanks for you andswer. First I tried to search an entire folder with avalon_td_gallery - zero results. I am trying rewrite rule but still no results :(

Comment: Sorry it didn't help. Have you searched for **register_post_type** as well? Or just **rewrite** on its own? Both avalon and the plugins directory...

Comment: omg! thank you! after 3 days! I totally forgot to look at the folder where is located plugin from theme. I searched in theme folder still. Now, one searching, 10 results, one row with rewrite function. Thanks!

Comment: @Martin if this solved your problem then accept the answer for others who have similar problem

Comment: So far I have not resolved :( happiness was premature. I search and rewrited "avalon_td_gallery" in all files, url is changed, but after click on "view gallery" i get 404 :/ Of course, I created a new gallery...

Comment: Hey Martin. My fault. I could have been clearer before. All is not lost. Your data is still within the wordpress tables. I've updated my comment